# Get a Stream of Entity from an Http4s Response with Circe

Tags: scala, circe, http4s, fs2, http4s-circe

I'm trying to retrieve a `Stream[IO, Job]` from an http4s `Response`, but the Scala compiler warns me that it cannot find any suitable `Decoder`:

```
Cannot decode into a value of type fs2.Stream[IO,Job], because no EntityDecoder[[+A]IO[A], fs2.Stream[IO,Job]] instance could be found.
[error]         retrieved <- response.as[fs2.Stream[IO, Job]]
```

The code that generates the above error is the following:

```scala
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import org.http4s.circe.CirceEntityCodec._
// Many other imports

"should return the stream of all jobs" in {
  for {
    response <- jobsRoutes.orNotFound.run(
      Request(
        method = Method.GET,
        uri = uri"/jobs",
        headers = Headers(Accept(MediaType.`text/event-stream`))
      )
    )
    retrieved <- response.as[fs2.Stream[IO, Job]]
  } yield {
    response.status shouldBe Status.Ok
  }
}
```

In the `build.sbt` file, I have the following dependencies:

```
// Many other omitted dependencies
"org.http4s"            %% "http4s-circe"                  % "0.23.14",
"io.circe"              %% "circe-generic"                 % "0.14.2",
"io.circe"              %% "circe-fs2"                     % "0.14.0",
```

The definition of the `Job` entity is:

```scala
final case class Job(
    id: UUID,
    date: Long,
    salaryLo: Option[Int],
    salaryHi: Option[Int],
    currency: Option[String],
    location: String,
    tags: List[String],
    description: String,
    localUrl: Option[String],
    externalUrl: Option[String]
    image: Option[String],
    country: Option[String],
    title: String,
    company: String,
    seniority: Option[String],
    other: Option[String]
)
```

I cannot understand what's going on.

Comment: What is the definition of `Job`? Also, if you check the [docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.http4s/http4s-docs_2.13/0.23.15/org/http4s/circe/CirceEntityCodec$.html) you will see that you are not importing what you want, rather you should import `org.http4s.circe._`, or even just `org.http4s.circe.streamJsonArrayDecoder`

Comment: Hey, Luis. I updated the question. Is it the `UUID` type?

Comment: I added the `org.http4s.circe._` import. Nothing changed :(

Comment: Hey, next time, try to create a MCVE of your question using **Scastie** that would really help. Anyways, I got it to compile, check this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/hzv7W8MoQyy357Vczw13Hw/6

Comment: Thanks, man. Next time, I'll provide a complete example using Scastie

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```scala
//scala 2.23.10
//cats-effect 3.5.3
//http4s-core 0.23.25
//fs2-core 3.9.3
//circe-core 0.14.6
//circe-parser 0.14.6

import cats.effect.IO
import fs2.Stream
import io.circe.{Decoder, Json}
import org.http4s.{HttpRoutes, Request, ServerSentEvent}

val routes: HttpRoutes[IO] = ???

def getEntitiesFromStream(request: Request[IO]): IO[List[Json]] =
  Stream
    .eval(routes.orNotFound.run(request))
    .flatMap(_.body.through(ServerSentEvent.decoder))
    .compile
    .toList
    .map(_.collect { case ServerSentEvent(Some(data), _, _, _, _) =>
      io.circe.parser.parse(data).toOption.get
    })
```

Where `request` can be something like

```
Request(
  method = Method.GET,
  uri = uri"/jobs"
) //no need to set MediaType.`text/event-stream`
```

(`.toOption.get` might be not desired, but it's irrelevant to the problem and to the example)

Scastie snippet: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eBZvMBW5Q1GIGhH4BUgz4w